# TypeSwitching in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, system.reflection

I took the following code from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/05/16/switching-on-types.aspx

```
static class TypeSwitch {
    public class CaseInfo {
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public Type Target { get; set; }
        public Action<object> Action { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Do(object source, params CaseInfo[] cases) {
        var type = source.GetType();
        foreach (var entry in cases) {
            if (entry.IsDefault || type == entry.Target) {
                entry.Action(source);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static CaseInfo Case<T>(Action action) {
        return new CaseInfo() {
            Action = x => action(),
            Target = typeof(T)
        };
    }

    public static CaseInfo Case<T>(Action<T> action) {
        return new CaseInfo() {
            Action = (x) => action((T)x),
            Target = typeof(T)
        };
    }

    public static CaseInfo Default(Action action) {
        return new CaseInfo() {
            Action = x => action(),
            IsDefault = true
        };
    }
}
```

and i am doing the following

```
TypeSwitch.Do(
                    p.PropertyType,
                    TypeSwitch.Case<Int32>(() => DoSomething),
                    TypeSwitch.Case<Double>(() => DoSomething),
                    TypeSwitch.Case<float>(() => DoSomething),
                    TypeSwitch.Case<bool>(() => DoSomething),
                    TypeSwitch.Case<String>(() => DoSomething),
                    TypeSwitch.Default(() => {                     
                        TypeSwitch.Do
                            (
                            p.PropertyType,
                            TypeSwitch.Case<Object[]>(() => Do()),
                            TypeSwitch.Case<IEnumerable<Object>>(() => Do()),
                            TypeSwitch.Case<IDictionary<Object, Object>>(() => Do()

                        )
                    );
```

p is of type `PropertyInfo`. Even when p.PropertyType is String it goes to the Default Case .. Why ? Shouldn't it break ? If there is something missing in the TypeSwitch , how can i fix that ?

Edit

I have no idea why everyone assumed that i did not debug it first and went on a down voting spree. But i  did put in significant amount of time on this . I checked , i am only passing ProprtyType as String it loops through CaseInfo for everything then it goes to Do and executes the Default Case .. The question is what am i missing ?
[image]

Comment: Why don't you step through the code with a debugger? Make sure everything runs as expected (it won't and you can see the problem right then).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you pass in `p.PropertyType` and later take `source.GetType()` which in this case evaluates to `typeof(Type)`.

Probably, you want to create an overload that takes an instance of `Type` as the first parameter (in contrast to an `object`).

**You can find such errors yourself by stepping through the code with a debugger. Compare actual variable values with expected ones.**

Comment: Thanks for the real answer :) but i am grumpy about the fact that everyone thoguht i did not try and debug it my self . Fixed it by having oveloads of Do one with Object as a parameter and other as PropertyInfo